# EF6 losing context between design and runtime

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an EF6 Database-First application that adds to a table. The Model appears to have generated perfectly (T4) and intellisense shows exactly what I'd expect at design-time. 
However, at runtime, the exception:

> The entity type UsedLoanNumbers is not part of the model for the current context."

occurs on the line that first references the UsedLoanNumbers entity:

```
using (var context = new NLNEntities())
{
    UsedLoanNumbers uln = context.UsedLoanNumbers.Last();
    uln.UserID = userID;
    uln.AssignedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    uln = context.UsedLoanNumbers.Add(uln);
    this.LoanNumber = uln.LoanNumber.ToString();
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I do have a second EF context in a separate DLL that does logging... They are named completely different, but are both modifying data in the same database:

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the context code:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace NewLoanNumber
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class NLNEntities : DbContext
    {
        public NLNEntities() : base("name=NLNEntities") { }
            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
            }

            public virtual DbSet<ErrorLogging> ErrorLoggings { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<LogEntryPriority> LogEntryPriorities { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<LogEntryType> LogEntryTypes { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<ProcessLog> ProcessLogs { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<UsedLoanNumbers> UsedLoanNumbers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Connection strings:

```
name="NLNEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/LoggingModel.csdl|res://*/LoggingModel.ssdl|res://*/LoggingModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=CSTestLSDW;initial catalog=LoanServicingDW;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

name="LoggingEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/LoggingModel.csdl|res://*/LoggingModel.ssdl|res://*/LoggingModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=CSTestLSDW;initial catalog=LoanServicingDW;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: Please include the code (generated and custom partial if you use one) for your dbContext (NLNEntities).

Comment: I haven't modified the default generated code at all. I tried to post it here and it's too long...

Comment: @Daniel A. White, yes and I've deleted and rebuilt the .tt files as well - several times

Comment: Ok - the issue was the stupid connection strings!!!!! I had the wrong .csdl .ssdl and .msl entries (Duh... Hangs head in shame)

Comment: Interesting to see that the initializer doesn't throw the error when you are loading a completely wrong csdl/ssdl/msl.